# Is it possible to move the Terran base on a defend order too?

Tags: starcraft

Defend order states:

> He may then immediately move and/or transport units to the chosen
>   area, as if he were executing a Mobilize order on the planet.

It does only say transport units, but the terran is the only one being able to move a base on a mobilize order anyways and specific trumps general in rules normally in a game.

So is there anything official? a post on fantasay flight game that had  a response? or what is the common practice on this?

Comment: Some active group plays on Discord and someone told me it was a legal move, so in practice it is considered legal, but I'm still curious about a real answer, might be ''nothing official confirms it''

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly after years of playing this game it is actually NOT possible, you move units as if you were doing a mobilize but you are not actually doing a mobilize so it does not work. Aldaris has conclave fleet with the ''mobilize'' trigger as well.